# Enabling CORS for Web API in AspNet.core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I've created a Web API using ASP.Net Core 2.0 wherein I've implemented code for enabling CORS as given below:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowFromAll",
                    builder => builder
                    .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            }); ;


            services.AddMvc();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors("AllowFromAll");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

But still I'm getting status **401: UnAuthorized** when tried consuming in fiddler.

Any solutions on this regards?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  <h3>HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized</h3> 
  <h4>You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.</h4>